# ASP.Net MVC slow JS load

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I have a partial view within my application that uses a custom js control.  The control effectively turns a listbox into a checked drop down list.  That works perfectly.  The quite lengthy code that deals with the rich interactivity for this (not the actual control creation) is in a seperate js file, referenced by the partial view.

When the partial view loads, there is a noticable visual delay where the listbox renders into the dropdownlist.  You initially see the listbox, and then the dropdownlist.

However, if I include the JS code in script tags within the view then there is no delay. When the page loads, the control is fully rendered.

The JS file does not contain the logic for creating the control, just my manipulation code.

Anybody know why there would be such a delay using the same code, but with the difference being caused whether I am referencing a JS file or embedding the code direct into the view?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tested this in different browsers? Have you used something like Chrome's [Speed Tracer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ognampngfcbddbfemdapefohjiobgbdl) to see where and how great the delay is? +1 for the well written question BTW.

Comment: @Bernhard, thanks for the comment.  I haven't used any other browser, as it's an internal application, where we only use IE. Do you know of any profilers for IE?

Comment: I have managed to get Chrome installed on a works machine, and that works fine so it does look like it is IE!  Damn browsers!

Comment: Sigh. The time we spend on [IE](http://www.wardontheweb.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/08/time-breakdown-of-moder-web-design.png)...

Comment: Use Fiddler to prove your assertion that hte JS is loading slowly in IE. You can see the time spent between when the page is requested, completed, JS requested, completed, in order to figure our where the issue actually is. If the issue is that IE is taking ages to parse your page and read that there is a new file to download then you will notice a larger gap between the page request and the JS file request. If the Webserver is taking longer to serve up the JS file then you will see a short span between page request and JS request, and a long time for the request to complete.

Comment: Another option:  open the IE developer tools (hit F12), switch to the Network tab, click "Start Capturing", then reload your page.  It will show all of the resources retrieved by the page, with corresponding timing, HTTP codes, etc.

Answer (score 0):

How many items are in the dropdown?

There is a [known issue](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21507456) in IE8 with rendering long lists, it can be seriously slow!

Is the script in the external file wrapped with $(document).ready(...) or similar which would cause it to wait for all other elements to be rendered before executing?